# Can not load biblatex with options

Tags: biblatex, package-options, xwatermark

it seems that I cannot load the `biblatex` package with initial options:

```
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber,
  date=long,
  dateabbrev=true
]{biblatex}
```

this gives me the following errors in the log:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
(biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
(biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.
...
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
! Package xkeyval Error: no value specified for key `style'.

(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
! Use of \blx@tempa doesn't match its definition.
\CurrentOption ->s
                  tyle
l.10701
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Here's a minimal document showing the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[
  style=alphabetic,
  backend=biber,
  date=long,
  dateabbrev=true
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a small but *complete* example and the log-file.

Comment: Something very odd is going on here, which suggests an issue beyond the snippet posted.

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer. It is an incompatibility with the xwatermark package:

```
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
```

If this package is included before biblatex it somehow breaks the option parsing for biblatex. As of now there seems to be no problem with xwatermark if it is included after biblatex.

Best,

Marcus

Comment: The issue is due to the fact that `xwatermark` loads `catoptions` which does nasty things when changing the default package option processing. It's quite likely to confuse also other packages.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
```

before biblatex has the same problem.

Comment: Yes, see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461783/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443158/35864. `menukeys` and `xwatermark` both load `catoptions` (maybe via a chain of package loading), which redefines some standard option handling and confuses `biblatex`.