# Error when using xwatermark and babel

Tags: babel, watermark, xwatermark

I get this error when using xwatermark:

> ! Package catoptions Error: '\XDeclareOption*' multiply defined in 
>   (catoptions)                package 'babel'.
>
> See the catoptions package documentation for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.457 \DeclareOption*{}
>
> ?

My code is something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}
...
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation 
...
\begin{document}
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `xwatermark` package loads `catoptions` which is very unfriendly towards packages not using it and that try to manage options in a nonstandard way.

Load `babel` before it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}

\newwatermark[allpages,color=red!50,angle=45,scale=3,xpos=0,ypos=0]{DRAFT}

\begin{document}

abc

\end{document}
```

[image]