# Problem with biblatex when using any options with usepackage

Tags: biblatex, errors

I'm really new to LaTeX. I'm trying to use the biblatex package like so:

```
\usepackage[hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}
```

When I try to build and compile, I get:

```
biblatex.sty error line 15131 Use of \blx@tempa doesn't match its definition.
```

This error only occurs when I try to use options for biblatex after `\usepackage`. I am able to use options with other packages. I have my default bibliography tool set to Biber, and Biber is the latest version (2.14-1).

Additionally, I'm running TeXstudio 2.12.22 on Ubuntu 20.04.1.

If I can provide any additional information, don't hesitate to ask! Thanks.

Preamble up to biblatex:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{refart}

\usepackage{tabularx} % Allows word wrapping in tables
\usepackage{fontspec}   % THIS REQUIRES US TO COMPILE USING XeLaTeX RATHER THAN pdfLaTeX
\DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{T1}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ } % Fixes "LaTeX Error: Command \nobreakspace unavailable in encoding T1."

\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}  % sets the roman font for XeLaTeX
\renewcommand\sfdefault{cmss} % sets the sans font for XeLaTeX
\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt} % sets the monospace font for XeLaTeX

%% Font settings suggested by fbb documentation.
\usepackage{textcomp} % to get the right copyright, etc.
\usepackage[lining,tabular]{fbb} % so math uses tabular lining figures
\usepackage[scaled=.95,type1]{cabin} % sans serif in style of Gill Sans
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{zi4}% inconsolata typewriter

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}   % For colors in table environment
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{relsize}    % used for changing text size in math mode
\usepackage{enumitem}   % required to add boldface enumerate
\usepackage{amsmath}    % used for boldface text in math mode
\usepackage{bm}         % also for boldface math
\usepackage{xfrac}      % for angled fractions

\newcommand\Tstrut{\rule{0pt}{2.6ex}}         % = `top' strut
\newcommand\Bstrut{\rule[-0.9ex]{0pt}{0pt}}   % = `bottom' strut

\usepackage{makecell, multirow} % required to essentially merge cells in a table

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % required to align the attention image with the text

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{marvosym}   % this package allows the use of different symbols
% see https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/LaTeX_symbols.pdf

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,frame=single,xleftmargin=3em,xrightmargin=3em}
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}
\renewmenumacro{\keys}[+]{shadowedroundedkeys}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{leftbar}{\sffamily\small}

\usetikzlibrary{chains,arrows, shapes, positioning}

%This gives Fig references (i.e. labelfont) in Sans Serif and bold using the caption package
\usepackage[labelfont={sf,bf}]{caption}

%This package and the environments (and command) defined below simulate a verbatim environment with gray background (used for command line code)
\usepackage{fancyvrb,newverbs}  % requires xcolor package declared above
\definecolor{cverbbg}{gray}{0.93}

% Inline code
\definecolor{dark-gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{.95}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}

% Use \begin{cverbatim} to implement    
\newenvironment{cverbatim}
{\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
{\endSaveVerbatim
    \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
    \colorbox{cverbbg}{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
    \endflushleft
}

% Use \begin{lcverbatim} to implement
\newenvironment{lcverbatim}
{\SaveVerbatim{cverb}}
{\endSaveVerbatim
    \flushleft\fboxrule=0pt\fboxsep=.5em
    \colorbox{cverbbg}{%
    \makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep][l]{\BUseVerbatim{cverb}}%
}
\endflushleft
}

% Use \ctexttt{} to have this environment inline
\newcommand{\ctexttt}[1]{\colorbox{cverbbg}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newverbcommand{\cverb}
{\setbox\verbbox\hbox\bgroup}
{\egroup\colorbox{cverbbg}{\box\verbbox}}

% These packages and the command definded below create keyboard symbols for when keystrokes need to be used within the text.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

% Use \keystroke{} to implement
\newcommand*\keystroke[1]{%
    \tikz[baseline=(key.base)]
    \node[%
    draw,
    fill=white,
    drop shadow={shadow xshift=0.25ex,shadow yshift=-0.25ex,fill=black,opacity=0.75},
    rectangle,
    rounded corners=2pt,
    inner sep=1pt,
    line width=0.5pt,
    font=\scriptsize\sffamily
    ](key) {#1\strut}
    ;
}

\newcommand{\parbreak}{\par \vspace{0.1cm}}

% A nicely formatted table for explaining inputs on a given page (inputt stands for "input table")
\newcommand{\inputt}
    {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}\tabularx{\textwidth}{ r | X }
    \rowcolor{dark-gray}
    \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Meaning}\\
        \hline\Tstrut\Bstrut
    }{\endtabularx}

% A faster way to write includegraphics with a frame, caption, and label for \textwidth images
\newcommand{\sshot}[3]
{
    \begin{figure}[thb!]\centering
    \frame{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{screenshots/#1}}
    \caption{#2}\label{#3}
    \end{figure}
}

% A faster way to write icons with caption and label
\newcommand{\icon}[4]
{
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]\centering
    \includegraphics[width=#2]{#1}
    \caption{#3}\label{#4}
    \end{figure}
}

\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace{14pt}}

\usepackage{titlesec}  % Allows subsubsections
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\usepackage[hyperref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sources.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: It will be easier to find where the error is if you give us a complete document that exhibits the error. So it would help if you add a documentclass, a `\begin{document}` an `\end{document}` and whatever more is needed to get the error, maybe `\usepackage` for hyperref with some options? I don't know, because I don't get an error when I try.

Comment: I'll info about the preamble as soon as I get the chance!

Comment: bingo, the log from your example shows `(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/catoptions/catoptions.sty`  (used by `menukeys`)

Comment: Oh wow. What do I do about that?

Comment: Just don't use those packages.  Also you probably don't want this `\renewcommand{\indent}{\hspace{14pt}}` that is redefining a tex primitive and somewhat brave,  `\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}  % sets the roman font for XeLaTeX` is rather weird for xelatex although not strictly wrong.

Comment: also `\begin{figure}[hbt!]` makes the figure floating to the end of the document quite likely as it prevents p so prevents the figure being placed on a page of figures.

Comment: The `biblatex` option `hyperref=true` is usually redundant. The default setting for that option is `hyperref=auto,` which does the same thing as `hyperref=true,` with the exception that `hyperref=true,` throws a warning if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is not loaded. Both `hyperref=true,` and the default `hyperref=auto,` produce hyperlinks if and only if `\usepackage{hyperref}` is loaded. This does not solve the underlying problem, but loading `\usepackage{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage[hyperref=true]{biblatex}` gets rid of the error. ...

Comment: ... Of course you will still get in trouble if you try to use different `biblatex` options. `catoption` just messes with the option processing too much. Anyway, `hyperref=true,` is almost always unnecessary and can be dropped.

Comment: @AlexEastman No need to include the full preamble of your document, just what is needed to show the problem. Better to make a test document which only includes what is needed. Here you could guess that your commands like `\Tstrut` and your environments like `cverbatim` are not relevant,  and exclude them (but of course testing if the guesses are correct!). Then you get a much smaller preamble, and you can continue to make it even smaller by removing bits and testing and you would get something similar to the document in David's answer but with usepackage for menukeys instead of catoptions.

Comment: Is there a better way to make an easy indent command? I'm not sure about the `\renewcommand\rmdefault{cmr}`, I actually didn't add that part. What should I use instead of `[hbt!]` ? Lastly, the reason I was trying to load `hyperref` in the options for `biblatex` is because I wanted my citations to be the same color as my links, but that didn't work. How can I color my citation links away from the default yellow? Thanks for your help everyone!

Comment: When the author was developing `menukeys`, I tried in vain to persuade him *not* to use `catoptions`.

Comment: By the way, the `catoptions` package has no real documentation except for a `.tex` file that cannot be compiled because it uses a document class and a package that are not on CTAN and can be found nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give very little clues but my crystal ball suggests that you have

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{catoptions}

\usepackage[hyperref=true]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

`catoptions` breaks most other packages if used.

The above produces

```
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/catoptions/catoptions.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
! Use of \blx@tempa doesn't match its definition.
\CurrentOption ->h
                  yperref
l.15131 
        
?
```

Comment: That's a good guess, but unfortunately I don't have `catoptions` in my preamble. I'm working on getting some more information into the post :)

Comment: @AlexEastman put `\listfiles` into your preamble and take a look whether `catoptions` shows up.

Comment: @AlexEastman you can surely put a complete document that produces the error so we can reproduce it,  you only need to include as far as `\usepackage{biblatex}` line so it should not be very big to post.

Comment: There's actually quite a bit before that, the preamble has a lot of stuff in it*.

Edited because the length of the document is irrelevant.

Comment: @AlexEastman you can post 40 thousand characters in a question, is your preamble really that big? But just delete every package that you can delete while still showing the error.

Comment: @AlexEastman You don't load `catoptions` directly, but you load `menukeys`, which *does* load `catoptions`. (See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461783/35864, related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443158/35864)

Comment: I got rid of menukeys and it worked, thanks!