# xwatermark still error after loading babel before it

Tags: watermark, xwatermark

I just face the exact same error with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443158/error-when-using-xwatermark-and-babel) case and just followed the same method just as it suggest, but it still remained error.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany,a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{book}
...
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
...
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{pmatrix} %The error shows this line is the source of problem, though
...
\end{matrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: don't use xwatermark it is not compatible with a current latex.

Comment: So is there any other way to use watermark for my document?

Comment: I normally use eso-pic or (with a new latex) the new shipout hooks. But draftwatermark should work too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer could give me an example for that? I don't get it, though

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think I have figured that out after following your suggestion. Thank you so much!