# Error: Use of \blx@tempa doesn't match its definition

Tags: biblatex, biber

The following MWE throws two errors:

1. "Use of \blx@tempa doesn't match its definition."
2. "Package xkeyval Error: 'backend' undefined in families 'blx@opt@pre'. \blx@processoptions".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

What causes this error? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`menukeys` is one of the Evil Packages™. You must load it **after** biblatex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{menukeys}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

There are other packages that act like this, see [the answers under this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/321045/203081). The fundamental issue seems to be that they load the `catoptions` package, which `biblatex` is allergic to.

Comment: your texsystem seems to be outdated. In a current texlive menukeys no longer uses catoptions and your document works fine.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My TeX Live is from 2022, and I'm willing to bet that countless people with my version are not going to update for another handful of years, if ever.

Comment: You get the error in `texlive 2019` with `menukeys 2016/08/08 v1.5`. In `texlive 2020` with `menukeys 2020/12/19 v1.6.1` it is gone.  So if you get it, you are not using `texlive 2022`. Check your log file to find out what you are really using.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer My apologies, I confused my two machines. One of them has TeX Live 2022, and one indeed still has 2019. Nevertheless, it's good to have `\blx@tempa` mentioned on TeX SE; the point still stands, although for the 2019 version.